# How to pass parameters to a custom JSONEncoder default() function in Python

Tags: python, json, flask

In my Flask application, I use a custom `JSONEncoder` that serializes `decimal.Decimal` objects rounded to two places.

```
class MyJsonEncoder(JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, obj, prec=2):

        if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
            return str(obj.quantize(Decimal('.'+'0'*(prec-1)+'2')))
        else:
            return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

The `prec` parameter lets me change the precision of the rounding. It defaults to two places. I want to occasionally call `json.dumps` and pass it a `prec` parameter so I can force the `decimal.Decimal` objects to round to 4 places instead.

```
json_string = json.dumps(some_data, prec=4)
```

But when I do this, the JSON module throws:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prec'
```

Is it possible to do what I'm trying here? I don't understand why the JSON module is doing anything with the `**kwargs`. Can I force it to ignore them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyJsonEncoder(JSONEncoder):

    def __init__(self, prec=2, **kwargs):
        super(MyJsonEncoder, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.prec = prec

    def default(self, obj):
        prec = self.prec
        ...

MyJsonEncoder(prec=4).encode(some_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for editing your response. Your initial response sent me in the right direction and I ended up writing something exactly like what you have above. Works like a charm!