# passing additional arguments to json.dump in python2

Tags: json, python-2.7

I'm using `json.dump` with a custom encoder in python2, and I want to pass an additional parameter to the encoder, this way:

```
json.dump(data, fp, type, cls=MyEncoder)
```

Following [How to pass parameters to a custom JSONEncoder default() function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50070905/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-custom-jsonencoder-default-function-in-python) I wrote the encoder:

```
class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def __init__(self, type, **kwargs):
        super(MyEncoder, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.type = type

    def default(self, obj):
        type = self.type
        if isinstance(obj, datetime):
            # there was the line:
```

but, in **init**, the `type` value is assigned to `kwargs['skipkeys']`, not to `type` variable.

What am I missing?

Would it be different in python3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump), the third argument to `json.dumps` is the `skipkeys` argument, and so that's what the `type` argument in `json.dump(data, fp, type, cls=MyEncoder)` is treated as; the fact that the variable is named `type` is irrelevant, as `json.dumps` never sees that name.  In order to make `json.dumps` see that name, you have to pass `type` as a keyword argument: `json.dump(data, fp, type=type, cls=MyEncoder)`.

Comment: @PaoloBenvenuto: Yes, it should.